# Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI. Use the expo start command to start the CLI again

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming, expo

i'm new to react-native i installed expo as mention in official page like below.

```
npm install expo-cli --global

expo init my-new-project
cd my-new-project

expo start(run this in my cmd)
```

**Get this error in cmd**

> [09:53:03] TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined

```
npm start(i did this too)
```

**Get this error in cmd**

> [09:47:17] TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined

**I get this error in my Browser** 
[Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI. Use the expo start command to start the CLI again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNDR3.png)

Answer (score 7):

Something is missing, Run following

```
npm install
```

and then

```
expo start
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an error from expo-cli. There is a thread in react native expo-cli github page. Please check out the link below.

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/213#issuecomment-441507128

If the above work around isn't working for you, please use react-native-cli and initiate the project.

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe expo not install correctly so you need to one more time run this command:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

then

```
expo start
```

Comment: I tried running the second command it says "run" is not an expo command. See "expo --help" for the full list of command... I am using macos mojave

Comment: having some problem. this solution didnt work for me

Comment: @Jitendra is this outdated? since I too got the same error as Neeraj.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug in the older version in expo cli, which has been removed. What you can do now is
run this command:

```
npm uninstall -g expo-cli && npm i -g expo-cli
```

Check this [Expo github issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/213) for more info

Answer (score 0):

use this command I fix similar issues like this

```
$ sudo npm install
```

*then*

```
$ sudo expo start
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using these two commands:

`sudo npm install` and then `sudo expo start`

Comment: it seems like you did the same thing as the other answers, did you possibly forget to add an additional step that you had to take?

Comment: I didn't need to take any other steps, just used those commands and my problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

So all the previous answer can give an hint but none of them explain why this is happening.
Basically could be the fact that expo wasn't installed but only run via

```
npx expo-cli init projectName  // for example
```

then even installing expo-cli won't work if after the previous command are been installed other dependencies such:

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react- 
native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
```

Basically you need to install expo and then install all other dependencies "run" previously with it.

So need to install expo-cli

```
npm install expo-cli
```

then install all the other dependencies