# Expo Developer Tools is disconnected and you can't reinstall watchman

Tags: xcode, macos, react-native, expo, watchman

After some time (and a few updates to my mac running currently `macOS Big Sur 11.4`) I did try to simply start my expo app by running `npm run start` which in fact is the same as running `expo start`

This opened expo in the browser and in CLI. After a few seconds `expo` disconnected with error:

```
Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI. Use the expo start command to start the CLI again.
```

and in the terminal window I found this error:

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:178:28)
```

Please note, this is a **different** issue than: [Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI. Use the expo start command to start the CLI again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474846/expo-developer-tools-is-disconnected-from-expo-cli-use-the-expo-start-command-t)

After researching I found out that I need to reinstall `watchman`

However, running `brew reinstall watchman` gave me warning:

```
Warning: You are using macOS 11.4.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
```

At the end of installation I've got a new error:

```
==> Reinstalling watchman 
Error: Your CLT does not support macOS 11.4.
It is either outdated or was modified.
Please update your CLT or delete it if no updates are available.
```

What do do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some steps are not required but running them **all** solved the issue:

- Update XCode to the latest version (currently: `12.5.1`)
- Delete `/Library/Developer/` by running `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/`
- Install command line developer tools again by running: `sudo xcode-select --install`

  - Click instal button in popup window and then Agree with T&C
- Open XCode and allow to install additional tools
- Run `brew update`
- Run `brew reinstall watchman` - that will finally update `watchman` and will take significantly more time than previously running the same command which ended with an error.

Now I can start `expo` fine and it doesn't disconnect anymore.